# Can I reset latlng coordinates for a custom map type?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made my own map using the google maps api. It is a custom map type based on a really big image.

Is there anyway I can reset the latlng coordinates so they are relative to my image and not the earth's default latlng coordinates?

I.E. Make the top left corner of the image (0,0).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with your own [custom projection definitions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ProjectionImplemention). I modified this [lunar surface example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) with a simple projection that takes the top-left corner to be (0,0) and bottom-right, (50,50). You will most likely need to change the values to work with your app.

I played around a bit with the limits and there looks to still be a hard limit of +/- 90 for latitudes and +/- 180 for longitudes. The longitude will wrap around at 180 degrees. That is, it appears to be impossible to define a custom coordinate of, say, (100, 200).

See the modified lunar surface demo here, click anywhere to display the custom latLng in an alert:

http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/79/

```
function percentProjection() {};

percentProjection.prototype.fromLatLngToPoint = function(latlng) {
    // pixel size of tile at zoom 0
    var max = 256;

    // define bottom-right corner as (50, 50)
    var x = max * latlng.lng() / 50;
    var y = max * latlng.lat() / 50;
    return new google.maps.Point(x, y);
};

percentProjection.prototype.fromPointToLatLng = function(pixel) {
    // inverse conversion
    var max = 256;
    var lng = pixel.x / max * 50;
    var lat = pixel.y / max * 50;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate the clear and comprehensive answer.

Comment: I have implemented your code, as well as this from the jsfiddle: `moonMapType.projection = new percentProjection();` However, it doesn't seem to be taking effect, is there something else I need to add for this to work? Do I need a minZoom of 0 too? Thanks

Comment: Have you linked the projection with the `mapTypes`, `mapTypeId` options (seen inside `initialize` in the jsfiddle)? I will have to do more testing to see if the min. Zoom matters, I don't think it should, though.

Comment: Everything worked fine but now my map doesnt load and neither do the markers. I've rolled back and am now trying to figure out what I need to do. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I'm wondering if your map code is structured similarly to the JSfiddle? If your code is accessible I could try to help by looking at it.

Comment: Yes of course: http://pastebin.com/1bnnEuqd that's what I'm working with at the moment.

Comment: Note: the markers appear but its just the map tiles which do not.

Comment: I tried your pastebin with the Google moon image and seems to work for me. I noticed a } brace missing for `initialize` (should be added right before `function getNormalizedCoord`, also remember that the visible range will be between (0,0) and (50,50) in the new coordinates, so change the starting map `center` to the middle (25,25) or somewhere inside the visible range. Added: try looking at the JavaScript console or output the result of the `getTileUrl` function and make sure the result is where your images are. Compare the latest code to the code that was working previously.

Comment: Thank you, it is fixed now. The only thing is that the latitude starts at 28. Do you think this could be because my map doesn't have a minZoom of 0?

Comment: So the top left corner is Lat=28, Lng=0? Yeah, I think it would be because the tiles above are not defined, or there's blank areas in your images. What about the bottom-right corner? Anyway, I think the easiest fix is to modify the projection functions and translate the values. I'm not so great at geometry anymore but try updating these two lines: `var y = max * ((latlng.lat() + 28) / 50);` and `var lat = pixel.y / max * 50 - 28;`

Comment: Bottom-right corner: lat=50, lng=26. I'm going to re-render the entire image so I can have a minZoom of 0 and see if that fixes it. If not, I'll try what you suggested and update you.

Comment: If you do the minZoom 0 try making that tile 256x256 pixels, so it's consistent with the moon example. This is only the second time I'm trying custom maps :)

Comment: The tile rendered as 256x256 but the actual image on the tile was only 134x112. That may be the issue. Is this a problem with how I rendered the image? I'm using maptiler. http://www.maptiler.org/

Comment: I pictured the map not to be perfectly square, so I think the only way now is to change those `var x, var lng` lines in the projection definition. The moon image had content everywhere in the 256x256 tile, but looks like over half of your tile is empty. I would leave the projection as is and add a click listener, to measure at which coordinates the top-left and bottom-right corners are, then add those offsets to the point<->latLng functions. Also, the "50" defines the width/height, so you'll have to measure 134/256 = 0.52*50 for the new value, and same for the 112. Depends how big you need it.

Comment: Like you said, the it didn't work because the image wasn't square. I'm going to work on it but it will take a while to perfect these coordinates. Thanks for the help and I will update you when I eventually fix it.